# Something goes wrong with PHP microtime parsing

Tags: php, microtime

Ok, I have this basics PHP logic made for measuring execution time in PHP, you can find it [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2058/determine-execution-time-in-php/). Everything was right, than I, instead of usual time execution range and format suddenly started to get incorrect results, like this:

> This page was created in 6.0081481933594E-5 seconds

There is absolutely no chance that script is created(parsed) in 6 seconds (script was empty with exception of time measuring code).
And, what happened with correct format? What does it mean 'E-5' I get on end every (incorrect) time usage calculations?
I just to get normal, usual time like 0.003454893745 and I can't remember that I've changed some PHP ini settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 6.0081481933594E-5

means

> 6.0081481933594 x 10<sup>-5</sup>

in other words, `.000060081481933594` seconds, or 60 microseconds.

Comment: Thanks very much. And, is there way to get things as they were? (.000060081481933594 instead 6.0081481933594E-5)

Comment: You can use [`printf`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to explicitly set a format string (and thus choose exactly how to print the decimal number).